# How to communicate between classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

I'm trying to build calculator based on tkinter. I also follow tips from [there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161569/gui-calculator-using-tkinter).
Program for sure is still in progress. I'm currently stuck because of this error:

> AttributeError: 'Calculator_GUI' object has no attribute 'main'

I have no idea how to get to work communication between both classes. I'm also asking for short review of what already is done. Thanks in advance!
Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Calculator_Core():
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = tk.StringVar()

    def buttonClick(self, a):
        self.input.set(a)
        #DEBUG:
        print(self.input)


class Calculator_GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.button = {}
        self.configure_gui()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.main = Calculator_Core()

    def configure_gui(self):
        self.master.title("Calculator")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.configure_input_space()
        row_number = 1
        column_number = 0
        a = -1
        text_buttons = ('789+', '456-', '123*', '0=/C')
        for button_row in text_buttons:
            for text_button in button_row:
                a += 1
                self.configure_button(text_button, row_number, column_number, a)
                column_number += 1
            row_number += 1
            column_number = 0

    def configure_button(self, text, row, column, key):
        self.button[key] = ttk.Button(self.master, text=text,
                                  command=lambda: self.main.buttonClick(text))
        self.button[key].grid(row=row, column=column)

    def configure_input_space(self):
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.main.input)
        self.entry.grid(columnspan=4, sticky='we')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Calculator_GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to 'make' the `self.main` before running the `create_widgets()` funtion, so this:

```
class Calculator_GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.button = {}
        self.configure_gui()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.main = Calculator_Core()
```

Should be like this:

```
class Calculator_GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.main = Calculator_Core()
        self.button = {}
        self.configure_gui()
        self.create_widgets()
```

Because the `create_widgets()` function runs the `configure_button()` and `configure_input_space()` functions which have references to `self.main`.